# How to interpret not significant fixed effects?

Tags: fixed-effects-model

I tried to make a fixed effect model to see the causal effect of GINI (independent variable) to Criminal violence (dependent variable). This is how I did:

I took 2010 data and 2016 data. (t1=2010 and t2=2016). I got a total of 59 observations for each year with a total of 118 for both years. And I made the following:

1. I made a multiple regression (MR) with all the data, and with some control variables:

```
desigualdadmultiple <- lm(Hom_int ~ Gini + Sex + PIB_capita + por_joven + 
                        densidad_pob, data = hom1016)
```

The results of this model is (1) = 0,666***  (significant)

2. Then, I made the fixed effects model

```
fixedhom <- plm(Hom_int ~ Gini, data = hom1016, 
             index = c("id", "tiempo10"), model = "within")
```

And then, robust standard errors

```
fixedhom.r <- coeftest(fixedhom, vcov = vcovHC, type = "HC1")
```

This is the result for (2) = 0.009 (not significant)

3. Then, I added some control variables:

```
fixedhom.c <- plm(Hom_int ~ Gini + Sex + PIB_capita + por_joven + 
          densidad_pob, data = hom1016, index = c("id", "tiempo10"),
               model = "within")
```

This is the result of (3) = 0.020 (not significant)

So, my main question is this one:
How can I interpret my results?
I don´t know if the model is completely wrong, or probably, my results tell me that with fixed effects model, without invariants in time, the relation Is not significant.
I m new in this. I appreciate a lot your answers.
Thank you

If you have any other doubts just tell me

[image: fixed]

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's not clear what you are doing here. What is the stargazer function (for linear reg. in R, the usual is to use lm())? What is the warning message that is half-visible in your screenshot? What are your variables?

Comment: I described better my question Peter and Monica. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Thanks. Could you edit your question to include the material in your comments? Then I can re-open this.

Comment: I already  edited my post Peter. is it ok?

Comment: Dear Monica, Stargazer function is just to show two or more results. The warning message was an error in the name of a result.